# Delphi / ADO : how to get result of Execute()?

Tags: delphi, ado

I have declared `AdoConnection : TADOConnection;`  and successfully connected to the default "mysql" database (so, no need to pass that code).

Now, taking baby steps to learn, I would like to `AdoConnection.Execute('SHOW DATABASES', cmdText);`  which seems to work ok, in the sense that it doesn't throw an exception, but I am such a n00b that I don't know how I can examine the result of the command  :-/

Halp!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@mawg, the `SHOW DATABASES` command returns an dataset with one column called 'Database', so you can use the `TADOQuery` component to read the data.

try this code.

```
var
  AdoQuery : TADOQuery;
begin
   AdoQuery:=TADOQuery.Create(nil);
   try
    AdoQuery.Connection:=AdoConnection;
    AdoQuery.SQL.Add('SHOW DATABASES');
    AdoQuery.Open;
    while not  AdoQuery.eof do
    begin
      Writeln(AdoQuery.FieldByname('DataBase').AsString);
      AdoQuery.Next;
    end;
   finally
   AdoQuery.Free;
   end;


end;
```

Comment: hmm, now I have another question. Tho output is gotten from  AdoQuery.FieldByname  but it looks like I have to match the field name to the command. Can I wild-card it?  (I would like a generic function to execute a command and get the result into a TStringList)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to reach the returned `_Recordset`.
If you don't mind using the Delphi components, you should use `TADODataSet` or `TADOQuery` to execute a SQL command which can return any results (or the more low-evel `TADOCommand`s' `Execute` methods).
If you wanty something realy simple, w/o all the VCL balast, you mignt want to try the `TADOWrap` class from [ExplainThat](http://www.explainth.at/en/delphi/adowrap.shtml) (MIT licenced).

Answer (score 1):

You must use an TADOQuery connected to TADODataBase. At property SQL you must include the SQl statament to retrive databases in SGDB. In SQL Server you can do this:

> SELECT * FROM sysdatabases

In MySQL must exist something similar to retrieve the names.

You can connect this TADOQuery to a TDataSource and a DBGrid to see visual result or use code to explore the result of the query (some similar to this):

```
ADOQuery1.Open;
while not ADOQuery1.eof do begin
  Name := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('DBName').AsString;
  ADOQuery1.Next;
end;
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need TAdoQuery to execute statements, that return results.

Comment: and you don't care to give a code example, despite my proclaiming myself a n00b?  Nvm, I have worked it out by now

Comment: I am sorry, but actually there are plenty already. You just need to use google or docs. Being a noob is ok. But being lazy noob is a disaster...

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to populate a grid why dont you use adotable ?

```
Adotable.open;
Adotable.first;
While NOT adotable.eof do(not sure about not or <>)
Begin
Put values in variant or array;

Adotable.next;
End
```

Then you can let any UI access the array or variant.
Or populate a dataset.